# Using any() and all() to check if a list contains one set of values or another

Tags: python, list, set, any

My code is for a Tic Tac Toe game and checking for a draw state but I think this question could be more useful in a general sense.

I have a list that represents the board, it looks like this:

```py
board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

When a player makes a move, the integer they moved on is replaced with their marker ('x' or 'o'). I already have checks in place to look for a winning state. What I can't do is check for a draw state, where none of the list values are integers but a winning state has not been set.

The code I have so far:

```py
if any(board) != playerOne or any(board) != playerTwo:
    print 'continue'
elif all(board) == playerOne or playerTwo:
    print 'Draw'
```

The if statement works, the elif does not. I think the problem is my 'or' operator. What I want to check for is: if the every item on the board is either `playerOne` marker or `playerTwo` marker. If I were to make the code:

```py
elif all(board) == playerOne or all(board) == playerTwo:
```

I would be checking to see if every place on the board was `playerOne` or every place on the board is `playerTwo`, which it won't be.

So how do I check if the board is taken up by a combination of `playerOne` markers and `playerTwo` markers?

Comment: That's really not how [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) work: _"Return `True` if (any/all) element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False."_

Answer (score 177, accepted):

**Generally speaking:**

`all` and `any` are functions that take some iterable and return `True`, if

- in the case of `all`, no values in the iterable are falsy;
- in the case of `any`, at least one value is truthy.

A value `x` is falsy iff `bool(x) == False`.
A value `x` is truthy iff `bool(x) == True`.

Any non-boolean elements in the iterable are perfectly acceptable — `bool(x)` maps, or coerces, any `x` according to these rules:

- `0`, `0.0`, `None`, `[]`, `()`, `[]`, `set()`, and other empty collections are mapped to `False`
- all other values are mapped to `True`.

The docstring for `bool` uses the terms 'true'/'false' for 'truthy'/'falsy', and `True`/`False` for the concrete boolean values.

---

**In your specific code samples:**

You’ve slightly misunderstood how these functions work. The following does something completely different from what you thought:

```
if any(foobars) == big_foobar:
```

...because `any(foobars)` would first be evaluated to either `True` or `False`, and then that boolean value would be compared to `big_foobar`, which generally always gives you `False` (unless `big_foobar` coincidentally happened to be the same boolean value).

**Note:** the iterable can be a list, but it can also be a generator or a generator expression (≈ lazily evaluated/generated list), or any other iterator.

**What you want instead is:**

```
if any(x == big_foobar for x in foobars):
```

which basically first constructs an iterable that yields a sequence of booleans—for each item in `foobars`, it compares the item to the value held by `big_foobar`, and (lazily) emits the resulting boolean into the resulting sequence of booleans:

```
tmp = (x == big_foobar for x in foobars)
```

then `any` walks over all items in `tmp` and returns `True` as soon as it finds the first truthy element. It's as if you did the following:

```
In [1]: foobars = ['big', 'small', 'medium', 'nice', 'ugly']                                        

In [2]: big_foobar = 'big'                                                                          

In [3]: any(['big' == big_foobar, 'small' == big_foobar, 'medium' == big_foobar, 'nice' == big_foobar, 'ugly' == big_foobar])        
Out[3]: True
```

**Note:** As DSM pointed out, `any(x == y for x in xs)` is equivalent to `y in xs` but the latter is more readable, quicker to write and runs faster.

**Some examples:**

```
In [1]: any(x > 5 for x in range(4))
Out[1]: False

In [2]: all(isinstance(x, int) for x in range(10))
Out[2]: True

In [3]: any(x == 'Erik' for x in ['Erik', 'John', 'Jane', 'Jim'])
Out[3]: True

In [4]: all([True, True, True, False, True])
Out[4]: False
```

See also: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all

Comment: I think instead of `any(x == big_foobar for x in foobars)` it'd be more idiomatic to write `big_foobar in foobars`.

Answer (score 0):

For the question in the title:

> if a list contains one set of values or another

it might be more natural to use set operations. In other words, instead of

```py
if any(x==playerOne for x in board) or any(x==playerTwo for x in board):

# or 
if playerOne in board or playerTwo in board:
```

use `set.issubset` (or `set.intersection`<sup>1</sup>):

```py
if {playerOne, playerTwo}.issubset(board):

# or
if {playerOne, playerTwo} & set(board):
```

If `playerOne` and `playerTwo` are set/list/tuple of values, then compute their union and test if it's a subset of `board`:

```py
if {*playerOne,*playerTwo}.issubset(board):
```

Also if the question is

> if every item on the board is either playerOne marker or playerTwo marker

then instead of

```py
if all(x == playerOne or x == playerTwo for x in board):
```

test set equality:<sup>1</sup>

```py
if {playerOne, playerTwo} == set(board):
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You can obviously assign `set(board)` to some variable beforehand so that you don't have to cast `board` to a set every time you need to test this condition.