# Python: Using an OR operator for variable number of inequality conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

Suppose I have `n` values in a list `x = [1.2, -0.4, 3.5, ....]`
I need to check if at least one of them is below zero.

So basically, if I had only two values, I'd have written
`if x[0]<  0 or x[1] < 0`

But now, I need to use the same or operator within a loop so as to check each one of the values in the list.

The command `any(x) < 0` seems to return `False` every single time.

How would I have to go about it?

Comment: `if any(value < 0 for value in X):`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`any` is not vectorized. You'd have to apply it on each object in `x`:

```
any(n < 0 for n in x)
```

`n < 0 for n in x` creates a generator that yields one value at a time from `x`, and is quite efficient since it is short-circuited, meaning it will break (and return `True`) as soon as it finds the first `n` that is `< 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use numpy for vectorized operations

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.2, -0.4, 3.5,0])
x<=0 # will return the array of boolean values
```

If you just need to check if the condition met or not then

```
any(x<=0) # will return true if array contains atleast one True
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `any()` or `all()` the pc will check if the elements in the iterableare True or False. Thus, you need to add a list comprehension to create the iterable:

```
any([elt < 0 for elt in x])
```

Comment: The brackets are redundant.

Comment: @Rishav Just to show the creation of the list. Might be a bit more clear for the OP.

Comment: @Rishav They are worse than redundant. `any` is lazy, meaning that it stops checking when the first `True` is met. With the brackets, you are forcing it to go through the entire list. The same holds for `all()`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis True. and you could change them to `()` to create a generator.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Not entirely correct. By using `[ ]` the entire list indeed has to be created in memory, but `any` will still be short-circuited so it will stop as soon as it finds the first trueish value.Consider: `class Foo(int): def __bool__(self): print('checked') ; return True ;; any([Foo(), Foo(), Foo()])` The output is a single `checked`

Comment: @DeepSpace How can it be that the entire list is created in memory **and** `any` is short-circuited? Do you mean that it short-circuits while parsing the already created list?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#any

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, it will have to create the full list in memory (more consuming than a generator) but it will still stop as soon as one of the element does not match the condition. i.e. it creates the list beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do the following:

```
any(value < 0 for value in X)
```

You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211828/python-using-any-and-all-to-check-if-a-list-contains-one-set-of-values-or-an)