# How do I get a filtered list from a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a homework assignment on csv files and I am asked to make a filter to check for keywords. Previously, I have already created a list of dictionaries and now I am asked to check for keywords within each dictionary. If the keywords are found, I was asked to then append that dictionary to another list called filtered list.

For background, the homework assignment is on Facebook posts by Donald Trump and here is a sample of the data

```
[{'link_name': 'Timeline Photos',
'num_angrys': '7',
'num_comments': '543',
'num_hahas': '17',
'num_likes': '6178',
'num_loves': '572',
'num_reactions': '6813',
'num_sads': '0',
'num_shares': '359',
'num_wows': '39',
'status_id': '153080620724_10157915294545725',
'status_link': 'https://www.facebook.com/DonaldTrump/photos/a.488852220724.393301.153080620724/10157915294545725/?type=3',
'status_message': 'Beautiful evening in Wisconsin- THANK YOU for your incredible support tonight! Everyone get out on November 8th - and VOTE! LETS MAKE AMERICA GREAT AGAIN! -DJT',
'status_published': '10/17/2016 20:56:51',
'status_type': 'photo'},
{'link_name': '',
'num_angrys': '5211',
'num_comments': '3644',
'num_hahas': '75',
'num_likes': '26649',
'num_loves': '487',
'num_reactions': '33768',
'num_sads': '191',
'num_shares': '17653',
'num_wows': '1155',
'status_id': '153080620724_10157914483265725',
'status_link': 'https://www.facebook.com/DonaldTrump/videos/10157914483265725/',
'status_message': "The State Department's quid pro quo scheme proves how CORRUPT our system is. Attempting to protect Crooked Hillary, NOT our American service members or national security information, is absolutely DISGRACEFUL. The American people deserve so much better. On November 8th, we will END this RIGGED system once and for all!",
'status_published': '10/17/2016 18:00:41',
'status_type': 'video'}]
```

currently this is the code I have

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
def get_update_with_keywords(status_updates, keywords, case_sensitive = "false"):
    # your code here
    with open(input_file, 'r') as infile:
        filtered_status_updates = []
        for row in status_updates:
            tokens = word_tokenize(row["status_message"])
            if tokens == keywords:
                filtered_status_updates.append(row)
        return filtered_status_updates 

keywords = ["clinton", "obama"] 
get_update_with_keywords(status_updates, keywords)
```

but I keep getting this output:

```
[]
```

I figure it's because I'm trying to append an entire dictionary into a list?!

Comment: Looks like you need to use `any()` and `in` to check membership, not compare the keyword list to the tokens list with `==`. In the code you wrote, you'll only catch if the entire tweet was "clinton obama!!!"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python using any() and all() to check if a list contains one set of values or another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211828/python-using-any-and-all-to-check-if-a-list-contains-one-set-of-values-or-an)

Comment: @G.Anderson how do I go about doing that? sorry I'm extremely new to python and don't really know what I am doing

edit: just saw your link, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use this as a substitute for checking if it contains in the list.. 
So your

> if tokens == keywords:

will change to

> sublist(keywords, tokens)

```
def sublist(ls1, ls2):
'''
>>> sublist([], [1,2,3])
True
>>> sublist([1,2,3,4], [2,5,3])
True
>>> sublist([1,2,3,4], [0,3,2])
False
>>> sublist([1,2,3,4], [1,2,5,6,7,8,5,76,4,3])
False
'''
    def get_all_in(one, another):
        for element in one:
            if element in another:
                yield element

    for x1, x2 in zip(get_all_in(ls1, ls2), get_all_in(ls2, ls1)):
        if x1 != x2:
            return False

    return True
```

credit to [check list if its a sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964155/checking-if-list-is-a-sublist)