# Check if a list contains any list

Tags: python

I want to check whether or not a list contains another list inside it. I don't care about the elements, I just want to check the existence of a nested list.

I have done this:

```
nested_list = False
for element_of_list in b:
    if isinstance(element_of_list, list):
        nested_list = True
```

But I was wondering if there is a more Pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using any() and all() to check if a list contains one set of values or another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211828/using-any-and-all-to-check-if-a-list-contains-one-set-of-values-or-another)

Comment: Rather: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342601/pythonic-way-of-checking-if-a-condition-holds-for-any-element-of-a-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `any`:

```
print(any(isinstance(i, list) for i in b))
```