# Python Spectrogram: Get Start and End Point of shown frequencies

Tags: python, audio, signals, spectrogram

i'm plotting the spectrogram of an audio signal. The plot shows the frequency for different time intervalls. The regions of interest are marked with a red circle because at these timings the microphon recorded a sound with an unknown frequency. The frequency is not important (at the moment). I'm trying to find a way to detect the start and endpoint in seconds for every recorded sound.

[image: Spectrogram]

Example first marked sound in spectrogram:

[image: First recorded sound]

In comparison with a normal line plot, at the beginning the values are zero and after ~4 seconds the values increase. The first value > 0 could be the start point and last value if value+1 = 0 is the end point. The first sound with the duration is detected.

This is my code and what i've done so far:

```py
sampleRate = 44100
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(audio_original, sampleRate)

plt.figure(1)
plt.pcolormesh(t,f,Sxx,shading='gouraud')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

The length of f, t, Sxx is [129, 17072,129]

```py
f # Array of sample frequencies
t # Array of segment times
Sxx # Spectrogram of x. By default, the last axis of Sxx corresponds to the segment times
```

Comment: Am I correct in saying the question is _how do you tell when a sound starts and ends from the spectrogram?_

Comment: If so, you are still better doing this from the time domain signal rather than frequency domain. That said, if this is a thought exercise, then `any` applied to a   `f` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211828/using-any-and-all-to-check-if-a-list-contains-one-set-of-values-or-another

Comment: E.g `if any(freq > 0 for freq in f[i])` then `start = t[i]`

Comment: If you are using https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html then you would index over slices `Sxx` `if any(freq > 0 for freq in Sxx[i,:,:])`